# Storing an NSMutableArray of NSObjects into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am currently writing an app for the iPhone, and one of the design requirements I need is to follow is the following:

Store `NSObjects` into a `NSMutableArray`, display data to a `UITableView` and save the data into `NSUserDefaults`. I am able to store an `NSObject` into a `NSMutableArray` and display it in the `UITableView`, but I need help understanding how to store the data in `NSObject` to `NSUserDefaults`.

My definition for `NSObject (.h)`:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface Name : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic)NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic)NSInteger score;
    @end
```

My implementation of `NSObject (.m)`

```
    #import "Name.h"
    @implementation Name
    -(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name andScore:(NSInteger)score
    {
    _name = name;
    _score= score;
    return [super init];
    }
    @end
```

This is how i store to my `NSObject`:

```
    NSString *newName = _submitNameTextBox.text;
    NSInteger score = 0;
    Name *name = [[Name alloc] init];//Name is the object name
    name.name = newName; 
    name.score = score;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableArray *listTemp = appDelegate.nameList; //main copy of my list is in app delegate, but i have it accessible by my uiviewcontrollers.
```

i add `NSObjects` in my `secondUIViewController`, and display the data in my thirdUIViewController, while my first is a basic manipulation screen of the data stored.

So my question is, given the code i used to define my `NSObject` and how i store said object to a `NSMutableArray`, how do i store the `NSMutableArray` to `NSUserDefaults` on app shut downs. Idea is the array needs to load the program array with data from the last run, so a user can keep track of his/her data.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.arrayOfPDF forKey:@""];
    [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: You can't store custom objects in `NSUserDefaults`. You need to encode them to `NSData` first.

Comment: That Init method might not do what you think it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to write Array containing string then :

Saving :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourArray forKey:@"ArrayKey"];
```

Reading :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ArrayKey"]];
```

As you need to write Array containing objects, you need to encode them and use Archiver.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:array forKey:@"array"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    array=[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
    return self;
}


- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    yourObject=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"array is ->%@",[yourObject array]);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the array when the app is terminated, using the `applicationDidEnterBackground` event of your App Delegate.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nameList forKey:@"dataArray"];
}
```

When your App loads again, you need to load the data using the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate of your App delegate.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   nameList = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dataArray"];
   if(!nameList)
   {
       //First time load or data is not saved yet
   }
}
```

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is not called for most apps. Saving upon entering the background would be a better choice.

Comment: @H2CO3: I just answered for OP's query about "how do i store the NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults on app shut downs. Idea is the array needs to load the program array with data from the last run, so a user can keep track of his/her data. "

Comment: @MidhunMP sorry it took a while, but i don't get access to macs to develop on very much. i tried the above code, and it seems to not work. I can't figure out if its not saving right or loading right.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is pretty simple. You are creating object of class Name, and showing it in UITableView. When you create an object and displaying it in UiTableView you work with the memory address, you just fetch the alive object from NSMutableArray, while you are trying to save the object in NSUserDefaults, and re-run the application you get nothing, because the reference will be killed, so instead save the Data put in your class object inform of, String or, Dictionary..